# How filter works in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have seen a tutorial that execute filter in mongoose schema

I want to know how this really work.

```
 const isConversationExist = user.conversations.filter(conversation => (
         conversation.userOneId === request.payload.friendId || conversation.userTwoId === request.payload.friendId)
        ,).length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break it up into pieces starting with

> user.conversations.filter(A)

The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function (A).

In the code, the provided function (A) is written using [ES6 arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
conversation => (
    conversation.userOneId === request.payload.friendId || conversation.userTwoId === request.payload.friendId
)
```

which can be rewritten (but not always) as

```
function (conversation) {
    return conversation.userOneId === request.payload.friendId || conversation.userTwoId === request.payload.friendId;
}
```

It basically says, for each element i.e. conversation, test if either of the conversation's user IDs is equal to `request.payload.friendId`.

If the test passes (as in function returns true), then the element will be added to the new array; otherwise, the element will be ignored.

> user.conversations.filter(A).length

This would be the size of the new array with all conversations that pass the test.

> user.conversations.filter(A).length > 0

This would be a boolean whether the new array has conversations that pass the test or not i.e. `isConversationExist`.

Comment: @Mickey thank you for your very interesting explanation.